# Не учитывается последние значение

Tags: javascript

```
let age = prompt("Введите свой возраст");

switch(true){
  case 0 < age && age < 12 : 
     alert("Ты еще ребенок!");
     break;

  case 18 < age && age < 35 :
    alert("Ты подросток!");
    break;

  case 35 < age && age < 45 :
    alert("Пора сажать дерево");
    break;

  case 45 < age && age < 60 :
    alert("Пора уже на пенсию");
    break;
```

Есть вот такой код, почему при вводе, скажем, 12 не выводится результат alert, а при вводе значения меньше 12 результат выходит, почему так выходить и как это исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
0 < age && age <= 12
```

но, я думаю у вас еще ошибка в том что промежуток с 18 до 12 у вас не обрабатывается, возможно вы имели ввиду

```
0 < age && age < 18
```

в любом случае если вам необходимо обрабатывать ответ для изначального вопроса, то стоит добавить меньше равно (<=) проверку, вместо меньше (<)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте оператор сравнения "меньше или равно" - `<=`.